# Volume of Revolution $f(x) = x^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, applications

Suppose you are given $y = f(x)$

I want to use *double integrals,* instead of the traditional washers.

Suppose even better, $f(x) = x^2$

Find the volume of $f(x) = x^2$, $x = 0$, $x = 4$, $y = 0$ <--- The region spun about the $x-$axis.

The area of $f(x)$ in the region is:

$$A = \int_{0}^{4} x^2 dx$$

How do I take this into a double integral? I dont see any relation with $dy$??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is symmetric around the $x$ axis.
\begin{align}
V 
&=
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \int\limits_0^4 \int\limits_0^{x^2} dy \, dx \, d\phi \\
&=
2\pi \int\limits_0^4 x^2 dx \\
&= 
2\pi \frac{4^3}{3}
\end{align}